# What causes garbage collector overhead when using InputDStream in Spark-Streaming

Tags: spark-streaming

I am trying do implement a simulation of spark streaming application. Initially I read all the batches and then I add them InputDStream in a different rdds. After 90 iterations I have read more than 5GB of data but only 14.4MB in storage mamory https://ibb.co/GHGsTLW what may causes this problem?

The size of data is only 75MB.

Is this the reason why I have overhead from garbage collector?

```
 val inputData: mutable.Queue[RDD[DBSCANPoint]] = mutable.Queue()
 val inputStream: InputDStream[DBSCANPoint] = ssc.queueStream(inputData)


    for (i <- 0 to total_batches + 1) {
      val inputRDD = ssc.sparkContext.textFile(inputPath + "/batch" + i +    ".txt", this.cores)
      .map(line => line.split(' '))
      .map(line => DBSCANPoint(Vectors.dense(GlobalVariables.newPointId(), line(0).toDouble, line(1).toDouble))).cache()
    inputData.enqueue(inputRDD)
     }
     inputStream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
      //rdd computation
     })
```